# Maximum payout job scheduling

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you have a set of jobs $1, 2, \dots, n$ with corresponding payouts $j_1, j_2, \dots, j_n$ where each job has a certain cooldown period $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$. If you choose job $i$ you receive a payout of $j_i$ but must skip the next $p_i$ jobs before you can choose another job. You can only choose jobs in the order provided, but you can skip a job if the cooldown period is too large. Find a recursive relation to determine the maximum payout and prove its correctness.

I've been struggling to come up with a recursive solution, but here's what I have so far: So suppose the optimal payout up to job $i$ can be expressed as $P(i)$. Then if we don't choose $i$, $P(i) = P(i - 1)$. If we do choose $i$, we take payout $j_i$ and must skip the next $p_i$ jobs. Then is it the case that $P(i) = j_i + P(i - p_i)$ (job $i$'s payout + the maximum payout from $p_i$ jobs before)? If so then we just take $P(i) = \max\{P(i-1), j_i + P(i - p_i)\}$, but I'm not 100% sure this is correct.

Example: If there are $5$ jobs with payouts $[2, 1, 4, 9, 6]$ and cooldowns $[1, 0, 1, 2, 3]$, then the maximum payout is $12$ when you choose jobs $1, 3,$ and $5$.

Edit: I believe my approach is incorrect, as it would result in a maximum payout of $11$ and not $12$ in the example above (would choose jobs $1$ and $4$). I think it might be incorrect of me to assume that choosing job $i$ means I want to add job $i$'s payout to the maximum payout from $p_i$ jobs before, possibly because it isn't really taking into account the previous cooldowns? I guess my logic might be slightly backward in that I should be skipping the next $p_i$ jobs if I want to include job $i$. Is it wrong to consider subproblems corresponding to choosing up to $i$ jobs?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your thinking?  What theorems, worked examples, or previously solved problems do you think might be relevant?  Please edit your query in response.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.

Comment: Personally, I am ignorant of this topic.  However, assuming that the problem is from a book/class, I strongly suspect that if you construe the theorems, worked examples, and previously solved problems as **tools** designed to help you solve the problem, and if you consider the **poker** approach of asking what the intent of the problem solver was (re problem is an application of the tools), and if you edit your query to show the tools to both yourself and mathSE reviewers, this may facilitate a solution.

Comment: "Example: If there are 5 jobs with payouts [2,1,4,9,6] an...you choose jobs 1,3, and 5." Is the assumption that one job arrives every "time-period" and instantly expires if the agent is not available? ie. it does not wait for the cooling period to be over?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Yes, there is no waiting time between jobs/you do not wait for the cooldown to be over; a cooldown period of $c$ means that the next $c$ jobs cannot be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to approach the problem through dynamic programming, which has both a top-down or a bottom up methods. In the bottom up method, you may want to construct a dynamic programming table. In the top-down, we want to construct a recursion (with memo-ization to avoid repetition of computations). The two approaches are equivalent.

In the example you gave,

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline 
\text{Jobs} \downarrow \text{time} \rightarrow & T=1 & T=2 & T=3 & T=4 & T=5 \\ 
\hline 
J_5 & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (6,J_5) \\ 
\hline 
J_4 & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (9,J_4) & (9,J_4)\\ 
\hline 
J_3 & (0,\phi) & (0,\phi) & (4,J_3) & (9,J_4) & (10,J_5+J_3)\\ 
\hline 
J_2 & (0,\phi) & (1,J_2) & (5,J_3+J_2) & (10,J_4+J_2) & (11,J_5+J_3+J_2) \\ 
\hline 
J_1 & (2,J_1) & (2,J_1) & (6,J_3+J_1) & (11,J_4+J_1) & \textbf{(12,$J_5+J_3+J_1$)} \\ 
\hline  \end{array}

The table is constructed from top to down, left to right.
The table above can be read as follows. The (i'th row, j'th column) corresponds to: "If one had j time periods, and access to jobs in row i and above, what is (i) the maximum payout one receives,(ii) the jobs selected".

This is different from standard DP algos like knapsack as the jobs seem to appear in reverse, but it may be regarded as a special case. As in DP algorithms, one can read off the final answer from the bottom right of the table.

Let $p_j,w_j$ be the payout and waiting time for job $J_j$. Then, the recursion that is apparent is the following:
$P_{(J=j,T=t)} =   \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{for } j <t \\
    p_j, & \text{for } j=t \\
    max(P_{J=j-1,T=t},p_{j}+P_{J=(j-w_j),T=t}), & \text{for } j>t
  \end{cases}
$

where j represents the row in the above table, t represents the column and $P_{j,t}$ represents the value in the table. Once you see the example above, the table can easily be generalized for general values of payouts and number of jobs.

You can read more about Dynamic Programming for different types of problems here: [Link to SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184869/what-is-the-difference-between-memoization-and-dynamic-programming)

I have linked the code here: [Link to DP Code](https://gist.github.com/p10rahulm/7a88d03dfac8bb19373b664a6ecd2825)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way we can prove the correctness of the algorithm?

Comment: Indeed. You must show 1) Base cases hold (for instance everything above the diagonal) 2) Show that the subproblem defined by the third case of the recursion is the best you can do 3) Show that the table correctly encodes the recursion. You can see more on proof techniques in DP, for example here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~nirkhe/cs38notes/recitation_notes/week2rec.pdf

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what's happening in the 3rd case. Why do we have to switch the order of $t$ and $j$ in the recurrence?

Comment: I'm sorry about the earlier notations. Do you agree with this now?

Comment: I think so; I'm trying to write up some python code to help me understand it. Does [this](https://pastebin.com/mMBSTUmK) make sense? I ran it but only get 11 and not 12 but my code may be wrong.

Comment: everything except the order of the loops. We loop down (jobs) and then left to right (time). Thus for each time period, we are moving down. Thus jobs should be the inner loop in your code

Comment: That makes sense to me, but switching the order of the loops still gives me 11 for some reason; I'm not sure where else I could be going wrong

Comment: See if this helps:https://paste.ofcode.org/36PuCGxmhUwgTGvDSLFd57e

Comment: Yes that helps, I see where I was going wrong; thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122731/discussion-between-cosmicflair-and-rahul-madhavan).